# ExecuteReader taking time, not in SQL server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am executing stored procedure using `ExcuteReader()` command. If I execute Stored Procedure in SQL server it is taking 2 secs. But in code taking around `2 mins`. I tried DataAdapter.Fill(). Still the same.

What is wrong in the code?

```
        spString = "usp_graph"
        sqlcmd_q.Connection = sqlCnn
        sqlcmd_q.CommandText = spString
        sqlcmd_q.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlcmd_q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientid", clientId)
        sqlcmd_q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@store", storeID)
        sqlcmd_q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attributes", attributeNumber)
        sqlcmd_q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attri1_idx", attribute1_idx)sqlCnn.Open()
        sqlcmd_q.CommandTimeout = 300

        sqldr = sqlcmd_q.ExecuteReader() // taking time here
        dt.Load(sqldr)
        dsGrid.Tables.Add(dt)
```

Comment: Are you doing anything like `set dateformat` in your stored proc? I've come across stored procs with a `set dateformat` slowing things down, yet it will run fine in SSMS when the query is cached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html). Everything you need to know about this subject, and more.